# C++ time(NULL) gives inconsistent results

Tags: c++, time, epoch

I have the following function to get the seconds since epoch for midnight of the present day.

```
long int midnight_time()
{
  time_t t;
  struct tm *local;
  t = time(NULL);
  struct tm timeinfo;
  local = localtime(&t);
  timeinfo.tm_year = local->tm_year;
  timeinfo.tm_mon = local->tm_mon;
  timeinfo.tm_mday = local->tm_mday;
  timeinfo.tm_hour = 0;
  timeinfo.tm_min=0;
  timeinfo.tm_sec=0;
  long int midnight_epoch = mktime(&timeinfo);
  return midnight_epoch;
}
```

When I called this function twice in code right after each other, e.g.

```
cout<<midnight_time()<<endl;
cout<<midnight_time()<<endl;
```

I consistently get radically different results, for example:
1367816400
1367812800

This is a difference of nearly 4000 seconds. I would expect the numbers to be the same. Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You could use `local` itself to get the `midnight_epoch` instead of creating one `tm` from scratch. That way you avoid problems such the one pointed by @jmihalicza in his answer.

Comment: Can you show in code how this would work and maybe add an answer below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isn't it that the tm_isdst flag is left unset? The difference is exactly 1 hour.

Comment: Does this flag matter? Shouldn't it give the same result in two subsequent calls of the functions since DST will not vary between function calls which happen within microseconds of each other.

Comment: @user788171: if you don't set the flag, it is left uninitialized and can thus have any value (depending on stack contents). Try it, I for one can't reproduce your problem with your original code so I can't test the fix either.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid problems caused by uninitialized memory locations (which seems to be your case), you should use the tm structure to which a pointer is returned by the `localtime` function. Here is an example:

```
time_t midnight_time()
{
  struct tm *local;
  time_t now = time(NULL);
  local = localtime(&now);

  local->tm_hour = 0;
  local->tm_min=0;
  local->tm_sec=0;

  return mktime(local);
}
```

@jmihalicza better answers your question, this is just a suggestion to improve your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as alluded to in @jmihalicza answer, is that you don't set the `tm_isdst` flag from the `local` struct. Presumably since your times are different by an hour the flag is opposite in your two structs one of the two times, causing the `mktime` to generate a time one hour different.

Instead of using `mktime` however, you might find it easier to simply back out the hours, minutes, and seconds (although this won't work well during DST transitions - I can't tell from your question if that's a factor for you):

```
return t - (timeinfo.tm_hour * 3600) - (timeinfo.tm_min * 60) - timeinfo.tm_sec;
```